# WKWebview inner view not resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have a WKWebview which I need to animate on a button press.The following animation code is being used.

```
  __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    __typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
      strongSelf->_webView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, strongSelf->_webView.bounds.size.width, strongSelf->_webView.bounds.size.height / scale);
      [strongSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  }];
```

I am observing that a lot of times inner content in the WKWebview doesn't resize after the animation. On digging deeper I found out that the bounds of an inner WKCompositingView in the WKWebview hierarchy stay the same while the outer WKWebview bounds change.

How do I make sure that the WKCompositingView bounds also change with the animation?

Comment: Whats with all the `strongSelf` and `weakSelf` and `_`? If you don't know what they are for then just remove all of them and use normal `self.`

Comment: @Tj3n: The `weakSelf` avoids retain-cycles. Since _Nikant_ accesses `_webView` by C arrow operator, he avoids null pointer exceptions by this construct, while `weakSelf->_webView` may lead to a null pointer exception. I think he knows very well what they are for.

Comment: @Nikant: If you're using autolayout, the `layoutIfNeeded` will discard all changes you applied to the frames or bounds. You should change the appropriate constraints instead.

Comment: @clemens I am not using autolayout. I tried removing the layoutIfNeeded as well and it did not help.

Comment: @Nikant Did you solve this issue?